# Django-funky-sheets {% include hot_template %} causes permission denied error

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to implement the django-funky-sheets (https://pypi.org/project/django-funky-sheets/) package, but I keep getting a Permission denied error as soon as I add the {% include hot_template %} tag.

I did the following during installation and setup:

```
pip install django-funky-sheets
```

settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'funky_sheets',
    ...
]
```

urls.py

```py
    path('adres/funky/create/', CreateFunkyView.as_view(), name='funky-create'),
    path('adres/funky/update/', UpdateFunkyView.as_view(), name='funky-update'),
```

views.py

```py
class CreateFunkyView(HotView):
    model = Adres
    template_name = 'bierviltje/vilt_detail.html'
    prefix = 'table'
    succes_url = reverse_lazy('funky-update')
    fields = (
        'id',
        'adres_title',
        'm2',
    )

    hot_settings = {
        'contextMenu': 'true',
        'autoWrapRow': 'true',
        'rowHeaders': 'true',
        'contextMenu': 'true',
        'search': 'true',
        'licenseKey': 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
    }

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateFunkyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['vilt'] = self.model.vilt

class UpdateFunkyView(CreateFunkyView):
        template_name = 'bierviltje/vilt_detail.html'
        action = 'update'
        button_text = 'Update'
```

vilt_detail.html

```py
...
<div class="row">
    {% include hot_template %}
</div>
...
```

The error message I keep getting is:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\[username]\[project]\bierviltje\templates'

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 156, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 154, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 176, in render
    template = context.template.engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 144, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 126, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 24, in get_template
    contents = self.get_contents(origin)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Envs\koka\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\filesystem.py", line 23, in get_contents
    with open(origin.name, encoding=self.engine.file_charset) as fp:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\chris\\koka\\bierviltje\\templates'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to a lot of this stuff myself. However, I have been playing around with django-funky-sheets for a while and also ran into the same error as yourself.

The way I tackled it was to recreate the necessary files in my app directory under my relevant template and templatetags folders.

I essentially used what was in the GitHub files: https://github.com/trco/django-funky-sheets/tree/master/funky_sheets

For example, I add a new files in:

- Project/app/templatetags/app/ called funky_sheets_tags.py
- Project/app/templates/app/ called hot.html and errors.html

I then refer to the templates like I would any other template (depending on how you have defined your static urls in the core settings.py). For me this looked like {% include "app/hot.html" %}.

Make sure you change the {% include errors_template %} in the hot.html file to {% include "app/errors.html" %}.

I know it is not the most practival solution but it works and I actually find it useful to see how the template works when trying to incorporate the handsontable with more complex views.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error while running using "Python manage.py runserver", and redirect at update url. Using the create button open data entry create url, and data logged. However. it doesn't save the data.

NB: Model fields customized.

```
class Assembly(models.Model):
    AssMake = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    AssModelType = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    AssSize = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    AssDateEdit = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.AssModelType


class vehicle(models.Model):
      vehiclesn = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True)
    vehicler = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True)
    vehicleName = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=True, null=True)    
    assembly = models.ForeignKey(Assembly, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vehiclesn
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).